# Error to compile after updating to Visual Studio 16.4.1 [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I have recently update my Visual Studio to the latest version up to now but after the following errors were presented on my solution:

[image: Visual Studio 16.4.1]

I have try to clean and rebuild the solution but is still the same.
Any solution for the problem?

Comment: I would start by eliminating the duplicate resource reference.

Comment: i'm stupid, that was my solution thanks!

Comment: @robert please place your answer below so we can close this question